# General entity"trk" is not defined and has no default entity error

Tags: html, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am trying to fix this validation problem:

> general entity"trk" not defined and no default entity and reference to
>   entity "trk" for which no system identifier could be generated.

**Here is my code:**

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=189019016&trk=tab_pro" 
   class="thumbnail">  
</a>
```

Can anyone see what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

[Zenith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226656/356541) pinpoints the general issue — `&` denotes the start of escaped character sequences in HTML, so the validator is trying to parse `trk` as a character entity (which it isn't). `&`s need to be encoded as entities themselves to prevent this confusion.

In XHTML strict, these need to be `&#` followed by unicode numeric entries (rather than shorthands like `amp`, `hellip`, etc), so `&` would be `&#38;`. I regularly use [this reference sheet](http://projects.kmi.open.ac.uk/ceryle/doc/docs/NOTE-charents.html) when I'm stumped.

The correct code for XHTML strict would therefore be:

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=189019016&#38;trk=tab_pro" 
   class="thumbnail">  
</a>
```

Comment: @Looneyviticus if an answer works for you you should click on the little check below the votes of the question. This means that you accept the answer. It gives you 2 reputation and the answerer 15.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `&` just before the **trk** with `&amp;`

Comment: @Looneyviticus That's fine - I should have noticed the xhtml tag earlier! Mine is the general version, Barneys version is correct in your instance.

Answer (score 0):

In classic HTML as well as in XHTML, a construct like `&trk=` is not allowed, since it is formally interpreted as an entity reference, and no such entity exists. This is really just a formality, because browsers don’t behave that way (or haven’t behaved in this century), but the error messages are annoying in validation.

HTML5 allows the construct, due to rather special rules intended to cope with this common case. However, currently HTML5 validators have a bug here and they report it as an error. There is an experimental version of the validator.nu software where this bug has been fixed: http://qa-dev.w3.org:8888/

In the future, you should thus be able to use such constructs without validation errors, if you use `<!doctype html>` (which may, of course, cause *other* validation issues.